# How can I run a PowerShell command that appears as if it were being executed on a remote PC (same domain)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to run a powershell command that executes from the remote PC. Any audit logs should show the command was initiated from the remote PC. All the PC's are in the same domain. I do have physical access to the machine but would prefer to kick the script from my local machine and then allow the remote machine to process the request.

Lets call the Remote PC with the name REMOTEMACHINE

If I run the following command, will the audit log show that it was initiated from my PC or from the remote PC.

```
psexec \\REMOTEMACHINE "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File C:\temp\test.ps1 -NoProfile -NonInteractive
```

Thanks

Both machines are running Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: If you want any possible audit log to show that the command was run from the target system you need to run it from the target system. Run it from somewhere else and that information may show up in some audit log.

Comment: This sounds awfully sketchy.

Comment: i know but its not for sketchy reasons.

Comment: I'm with Ansgar.  The security and auditing subsystems were designed specifically to disallow what you're wanting to do.  They wouldn't be much use otherwise.